# Creating a new row on existing table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

i have a Person classs

```
@interface Person : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * area;
@property (nonatomic, strong) int pin;
- (id) initWithName:(NSString *)anName andAreaName:(NSString *)anArea andPin:(int)aPin;
```

First i am reading a sqlite DB and fetching the a list of data i.e. name,area & pin.
Then i create an object of Person class & adding these fetched item in to it .Finally i add this object into an array.Now based on this array i am creating an table view & showing all these 3 data in different rows of a table view.

But now i have a Add New Name option is there on selection of which a pop up with text field will appear and on selection of submit option , a new row will be created with only name field in my table view.

So for this i have to update my old array or update initWithName: ?

Please guide me how to do this?

Comment: Could you post the code where/how you populate your tableview ?

Comment: Those other properties of your Person object will be nil unless you set them. Are you just setting the name when you add the new Person?

Comment: When i do add name operation , i want to add only name other fields can be empty.So a new row will create at bottom with name field only.

Comment: Create new person object, add to array and do a reloadData or insertRow on the table view.

Comment: Person *person=[self.retrivedPersons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];         
    cell.personnameLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",person.name];

Comment: By the way, I don't think you can use the `strong` qualifier with a primitive data type like `int`. It should be `@property (nonatomic) int pin;`

Comment: @ACB if i create a new person object alloc init it then i have only name field what about other fields what should i put in .Also what about my old data i dont want to loose it.

Comment: @SimFox, Added as answer, since I cant add it as comment. You wont lose your old data if you are just adding an object on to the same array.

Comment: just add data to ary and then reload table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this as follows,

Step 1:-

Create a Person object as follows,

```
Person *person = [[Person alloc] initWithName:@"Name" andAreaName:@"" andPin:0];
```

You can later add `area` and `pin` as,

```
person.area = @"Area";
person.pin = 10;

//or just do, 
Person *person = [[Person alloc] initWithName:@"Name" andAreaName:@"Area" andPin:10];
//if you have Area and Pin already available, you can use the above line itself.
```

Step 2:-

Add this to data source array of table,

```
[self.array addObject:person];
```

Step 3:-

```
[self.tableView reloadData];//or do an insert row call on this tableview
```

Comment: Thanks @ACB , i will check it & Let it you know :)

Comment: @ACB Thanks :) if i need to fetch the last pin number of a person from this self.array how can i get that?

Comment: @SimFox, Check this, `[[self.array lastObject] pin]`. If you find this answer is helpful, you can also press on the up arrow above the number 2.